# What is the good way to create dynamic check boxes in list view and write click event in Android?

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, listactivity

Here is my scenario.

I have a class that extended `ListActivity` class. In that class I receive a `JSON String`. Using that I make `HashMap`to include those values. Then I add those `HashMap` objects to the `ArrayList`. Then I make my list view. To create `ListView` I extend `ArrayAdapter` class.

Think that `hashmap` object contain only a name. when I creating the view I show that name a check box. The count of `hashmap` objects can be change dynamically.

My list view like this.......

```
================================
name 1                    []
================================
name 2                    []
================================
name 3                    []
================================

([] is my check box )
```

I can make this list view.But how I write click event to those check boxes??
Only I can do is, write a `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)`  method for the list view in the class that extended `ListActivity` .
How I write event when check box clicked.
Or do I want change the way that I make list view ??

Here is my `ArrayAdapter` Class........

```
public class TestClass1 extends
        ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {



    private Activity context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrayList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private TextView mName;
    private CheckBox mCheckBox;

    public TestClass1(Activity context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrayList) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_view_category_type);
        this.context = context;
        this.myArrayList= myArrayList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null)
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_category_type_save, null);

        mName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_name);
        mCheckBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.my_check_box);

        categoryName.setText(myArrayList.get(position).get("name"));

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

}
```

Comment: post your arrayadapter extending class.

Comment: Use ToggleButton instead of CheckBox and set its background as you want.

Comment: Click event is added in the getView() method of Adapter class. Post your adapter code so that i can help you better.

Comment: you can use imageview instead of checkbox. and maintain a flag for checked and unchecked button

Comment: I added ArrayAdapter Class

Comment: @Dev513 do you want to check the checkbox  even if it clicked else where in the list item or do you want to check the checkbox only when the checkbox is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Android ListView Checkbox Example - OnItemClickListener() and OnClickListener()](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html) might provide some idea for your problem.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add comment and give some feedback if this answer is not correct. I'll update or delete if necessary.

Comment: Don't delete. I think it might help.